How can I optimise this code which turns Snake-Cased String to a Camel_Cased String
import re;
def snaketopascal(snake):
    plist = [
        snake[i].upper() if i == 0 else
        '' if snake[i] == '_' else
        snake[i].upper() if re.search('_.', snake[i-1] + snake[i]) else
        snake[i] if snake[i].lower()
        else snake[i]
        for i in range(len(snake))
    ]
    pascal = "".join(plist)
    return pascal
def main():
    print(snaketopascal("i_am_a_snake_cased_string"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

#please use list comprehension in the answers

The Code I wrote was by mere hit and trial and the code seems unoptimized to me

Your code can be optimized by removing the unnecessary semicolon in the fist line. The source code file will then occupy less space.

This might be better suited towards [codereview.se] but read their guidelines before posting

@Elerium115 you've always been able to use semi-colons to put more than one statement on a single line: paste foo=3;print(foo) into your REPL and it will print 3 to STDOUT (although it's considered bad style most places). It's also (as I think you're pointing out) pointless the way the OP did it after an import though.

that's my point. You can save hard drive memory by removing the unnecessary semicolon from the first line.

@JaredSmith my gratitude for the explanation

Why not use builtins functions?
'i_am_a_snake_cased_string'.title().replace('_', '')

If you still want to use regex you can use findall to find all the patterns you can use re.findall
def snaketopasca(snake):
    for match in re.findall('_.', snake):
        snake = snake.replace(match, match[-1].upper())
    return snake[0].upper() + snake[1:]

or re.finditer if you want to slice the string instead of using replace
def snaketopascal(snake):
    for i, match in enumerate(re.finditer('_.', snake)):
        snake = snake[:match.start()-i] + match.group()[-1].upper() + snake[match.end()-i:]
    return snake[0].upper() + snake[1:]


I've been writing Python for more than a decade and never encountered the title method on strings. Nice!

thanks Guy , I  never though of that , but how would i implement the upper case(s) in the pascal case
